# Reading weird date format in hive

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark-sql, hive, format

I have a column which contians date as string but in many formats like - `dd/MM/yy`, `dd/MMM/yyy` .. etc etc. And I am using the following code to convert all strings to one specific date format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) in hive :

```
select 
      from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('31/02/2021','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but this gives me **2021-03-03** in HIVE.

Is there any other way to identify such invalid dates and give null.

Answer (score 1):

Assume, you recognized format correctly and it is exactly 'dd/MM/yyyy' and date is invalid one '31/02/2021'.

unix_timestamp function in such case will move date to the next month and there is no way to change it's behavior. But you can check if the date double-converted from original string to timestamp and back to original format is the same. In case it is not the same, then the date is invalid one.

```
    case 
        -- check double-converted date is the same as original string
        when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_col,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'dd/MM/yyyy') = date_col
            --convert to yyyy-MM-dd if the date is valid
            then from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('31/02/2021','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
        else null  -- null if invalid date
     end as date_converted
```